Where have the ESR releases moved to please?
I logged in as usual and visited https://lab.civicrm.org/esr/core/-/releases but got a 404.
Formerly this was where I found the releases.
In fact https://lab.civicrm.org/esr/ gives a 404.
I've hunted around https://lab.civicrm.org/ and Googled but not been able to find where you can download the ESR release. The latest post I can find on here points the questioner to https://lab.civicrm.org/esr/core/-/releases, does anyone have more up to date information please?
Many thanks

It's still in the same place. Things to check:

Are you actually logged in to lab.civicrm.org!
Has your esr access expired? You can check by looking at your user account on civicrm.org - in the memberships section.


Many thanks, our access had just expired.  Now engaged with the rather byzantine method of trying to renew it.

Thanks for the suggestion to check on civicrm.org memberships section.  Our membership is listed as, "Supporting Member - Annual".  I assume this is correct but I don't know.  Definitely logged into lab.civicrm.org but no esr access :-(  Any help much appreciated.  TIA.

Possibly Josh from core has to update your access so there might be a delay - not sure if it's automated. If it's not updated soon you can ping him at https://chat.civicrm.org.
